# Selecting the method to compare the frequency in two groups with repeated measures in each group

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, glmm, frequency

I have two dichotomous variables determining the cut-off point in the measurements taken before and after the manipulation. Not all observations are independent of each other, as for some subjects measurements were made before and after several times at different time intervals.For others, only one observation is available. The data frame looks like this:

```
   ID  ODC1  ODC2
1   2  TRUE FALSE
2   3 FALSE FALSE
3   3 FALSE FALSE
4   3 FALSE  TRUE
5   3 FALSE FALSE
6   3 FALSE FALSE
7   3 FALSE FALSE
8   3 FALSE FALSE
9   3 FALSE FALSE
10  5 FALSE FALSE
11  5 FALSE FALSE
12  4 FALSE FALSE
13  6  TRUE FALSE
14  7 FALSE  TRUE
15  9  TRUE FALSE
16  9 FALSE  TRUE
17  9 FALSE FALSE
18 11 FALSE FALSE
19 12  TRUE FALSE
20 13 FALSE FALSE
21 14  TRUE  TRUE
22 15 FALSE FALSE
23 14 FALSE FALSE
24 18  TRUE  TRUE
25 21 FALSE FALSE
26 22 FALSE FALSE
27 22 FALSE FALSE
28 23 FALSE FALSE
29 24  TRUE  TRUE
30 26  TRUE  TRUE
31 25  TRUE  TRUE
32 25 FALSE FALSE
33 26  TRUE FALSE
34 25 FALSE FALSE
35 25 FALSE  TRUE
36 26 FALSE FALSE
37 26  TRUE FALSE
38 24  TRUE  TRUE
39 28 FALSE  TRUE
40 29 FALSE FALSE
41 29 FALSE FALSE
42 29 FALSE FALSE
43 31 FALSE FALSE
44 31 FALSE FALSE
45 31 FALSE FALSE
46 32  TRUE FALSE
47 33 FALSE FALSE
48 34  TRUE FALSE
49 34  TRUE FALSE
50 35  TRUE  TRUE
51 36 FALSE  TRUE
52 37 FALSE  TRUE
53  3 FALSE FALSE
54  3 FALSE FALSE
55 39 FALSE FALSE
56 39 FALSE FALSE
57 40 FALSE FALSE
58 41  TRUE  TRUE
59 43 FALSE FALSE
60 43 FALSE FALSE
61  6 FALSE FALSE
62 44 FALSE FALSE
63 46 FALSE FALSE
64 46 FALSE FALSE
65 47 FALSE FALSE
66 47 FALSE FALSE
67 48 FALSE FALSE
68 49 FALSE FALSE
69 50 FALSE FALSE
70 51 FALSE FALSE
71 53  TRUE  TRUE
```

Using two dichotomous variables, I get the following contingency table:

```
       FALSE TRUE
ODC1   53     18
ODC2   55     16
```

**What statistical method should he use to determine if the frequencies differ between the study groups?**

I have considered using logistic GLMM but I am not sure how to form the model or how to interpret it. I also considered the exact McNemar's test, but I don't think its assumptions are met.

Answer (score 0):

Comments:

If you had 142 subjects in your $2\times 2$ table. then you could
test whether the proportion of `TRUE`s is the same in the OCD1 and OCD2 groups.

However, it is not clear that you have data suitable to be
summarized in this way. I am not sure what you mean by "Not all observations are independent of each other, as for some subjects measurements were made before and after several times at different time intervals. For others, only one observation is available."

The data frame provided does not clarify this. [The meaning
of `ID` is unclear. Does it mean you have only 71 different people? If you have paired responses, then most pairs are in agreement, and the few that are not, disagree about equally between `TF` and `FT`.]

```
TBL = rbind(c(53,18), c(55,16));  TBL
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   53   18
[2,]   55   16
```

Also, even if this table correctly represents your data, a
chi-squared test would not show a difference at the 5% level because
the P-value $0.8441 > 0.05.$

```
chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with Yates' continuity correction

data:  TBL
X-squared = 0.038671, df = 1, p-value = 0.8441
```

This test is essentially equivalent to testing whether the
difference between sample proportions $\hat p_1 = 19/71 = 0.254$
and $\hat p_2 = 16/71 - 0.275$ are significantly different at the 5% level. The two tests give the same P-value.

```
prop.test(c(18, 16), c(71,71))

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(18, 16) out of c(71, 71)
X-squared = 0.038671, df = 1, p-value = 0.8441
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.1262163  0.1825543
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.2535211 0.2253521
```

You can try these tests again when you are able to give two columns
of independent responses.